# How to redirect or load a view depending upon condition in react-native-iap purchase

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, react-native-iap

What I want to achieve is to redirect or show a view upon successful purchase. Purchase is successful but the state variable is not updating inside validateReceiptIos handler.

I checked the validation of the receipt but after that not even able to redirect to another page or load a view on the condition. I am attaching a code snippet below.

```js
const productIds = ['xxx_xx_xx'];


const InAppPurchase = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [purchased, setPurchased] = useState(false);

    const [email, setEmail] = useState({
        emailText: '',
        emailValidity: false,
        emailErrorText: null,
    });

    const [name, setName] = useState({
        nameText: '',
        nameValidity: false,
        nameErrorText: null,
    });

    const validateUserName = (text) => {
        if (text.length < 1) {
            setName({ nameText: text, nameValidity: false, nameErrorText: 'Name cannot be empty' });
        }
        else { setName({ nameText: text, nameValidity: true, nameErrorText: '' }); }
    };

    const validateEmail = (text) => {
        let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        if (reg.test(text) === false && text.length > 0) {
            setEmail({ emailText: text, emailValidity: false, emailErrorText: 'Invalid email' });
        } else if (text.length < 1) {
            setEmail({ emailText: text, emailValidity: false, emailErrorText: 'Email cannot be empty' });
        }
        else { setEmail({ emailText: text, emailValidity: true, emailErrorText: '' }); }
    };


    const validate = async (receipt, purchase) => {
        const receiptBody = {
            "receipt-data": receipt,
            "password": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
        const result = await IAP.validateReceiptIos(receiptBody, true).catch(() => {

        }).then((receipt) => {
            try {
                const renewalHistory = receipt.latest_receipt_info;
                const expiration = renewalHistory[renewalHistory.length - 1].expires_date_ms;
                // const expiration = renewalHistory[0].expires_date_ms;
                let expired = Date.now() > expiration;
                if (!expired) {
                    IAP.finishTransaction(purchase);
                    setPurchased(true);   //***Not updating the state variable***
                    //navigation.navigate('Success') //***Not even navigate to another page***
                } else {
                    Alert.alert("Purchase expired", "Your subscription has been expired, please resubscribe to continue using the app")
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        IAP.getProducts(productIds).then(res => {
            setProducts(res);
        })

        const purchaseUpdateSubscription = IAP.purchaseUpdatedListener(purchase => {
            const receipt = purchase.transactionReceipt;
            if (receipt) {
                validate(receipt, purchase)
            }
        })
        return () => {
            purchaseUpdateSubscription.remove();
        }
    }, []);

    if (purchased) {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.containerInner}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column" }}>
                        <View style={styles.logoSuccessSection}>
                            <Image style={styles.successLogo} source={require('../images/success.png')} />
                        </View>
                        
                        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')}>
                                <Text style={styles.signText}>CONTINUE</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.containerInner}>
                    <View style={styles.logoSection}>
                        <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('../images/logo.jpg')} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.headerText}>PREMIUM ACCESS</Text>
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.featureContainer}>
                        <ScrollView style={{ flexDirection: 'column', paddingVertical: 20 }}>
                            <TextInput blurOnSubmit={true} autoCapitalize='none' placeholderTextColor="#736c6c"
                                style={{ height: 40, borderColor: '#d6d8e1', borderWidth: 1, paddingHorizontal: 10 }} placeholder="Email" onChangeText={(text) => validateEmail(text)} onSubmitEditing={(event) => setEmail({ emailText: event.nativeEvent.text })}
                            />
                            {email.emailValidity === false ? <Text style={styles.errorTextStyle}>{email.emailErrorText}</Text> : null}

                            <TextInput blurOnSubmit={true} autoCapitalize='none' placeholderTextColor="#736c6c"
                                style={{ height: 40, borderColor: '#d6d8e1', borderWidth: 1, paddingHorizontal: 10, marginVertical: 5 }} placeholder="Name" onChangeText={(text) => validateUserName(text)} onSubmitEditing={(event) => setName({ nameText: event.nativeEvent.text })}
                            />
                            {name.nameValidity === false ? <Text style={styles.errorTextStyle}>{name.nameErrorText}</Text> : null}
                        </ScrollView>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        {products.map((product, i) =>
                            <TouchableOpacity key={i} style={styles.button} onPress={() => {
                                if (email.emailValidity === false || name.nameValidity === false) {
                                    Alert.alert(
                                        "Email & Name fields cannot be empty.",
                                        "",
                                        [
                                            { text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed") }
                                        ],
                                        { cancelable: false }
                                    );
                                } else {
                                    IAP.requestSubscription(product.productId);
                                }

                            }}>
                                <Text style={styles.signText}>SUBSCRIBE - $9.99/Month</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        )}
                    </View>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
}
```